# how to join fields like product skus in sales order grid collection in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to join product skus and order comments and order product custom option in sales order grid collection.

I have aleady added columns in ui component but values is not rendered because of collection does not have this values.

I have tried with column renderer is working but filter is not working.

```
vender/modulename/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Skus.php
```

Is it possible to filter with sku in sales order grid ?
or is it possible to disable filter for one column then how ?

Please help me for fix this issue